# PHP error line numbers completely off

Tags: php, debugging, syntax-error

I don't know what's going on with my PHP. I'm using a bunch of classes and a semi-MVC framework that I developed myself (as an experiment). So the PHP file is including a lot of class files.

My PHP line numbers for error messages are completely off and therefore useless and making it impossible for me to debug. For example, right now I'm getting an error message that says:

```
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /view.php on line 209
```

The only problem is: there is no ')' anywhere near line 209. Even worse, if I put `die()` on line 200 or so, it still gives me an error message, now pushed down to line 210. So clearly the line of code is being taken into account, yet for some reason it's not dying.

Another thing is, it's including a header.php file prior to this line. The header file basically just outputs some HTML, and works fine on other pages. Yet on this page, it doesn't even output the header; it's just dying with a blank page and that error message.

Is there anything I can do to use more reliable debugging? If I could have an accurate line number, I'm sure I'd find the bug easily.

**Edit: I found the bug. The point of this question is not to solve the unexpected ')' bug. The point is: why are the line numbers inaccurate? The actual error message was on line 218, not 209 or 210.**

Comment: The view is related to some data form or what?

Comment: use any editor like eclipse. which will show you the syntax error if it occurs.

Comment: Okay, but why are the line numbers being inaccurate in the first place?

Comment: look for the opening parentese before line 209

Comment: You probably haven't closed a bracket somewhere and PHP is trying to match it. Is line 209 near the end of the file?

Comment: Is it possible that some of your new lines in the source code are \n while some of them are \r\n?

Comment: I've found the error which was, I was doing `( $test ? $a : $b )` but I put a `.` instead of a `:` on accident. But you guys are missing the point of the question: why are the line numbers so inaccurate? The actual error was on line 218, not 209 or 210.

Comment: Maybe your IDE is wrapping code and numbering things incorrectly?

Comment: It depends on the error. If you miss a comma in a multi-line array declaration on line 200, PHP will complain about unexpected syntax on line 201. Similarly other errors may propagate further down, depending on the exact problem. This is hard to answer without more information.

Comment: Could the problem have been that comments weren't being taken into account?  For some reason, I remember that comments are ignored when it comes to error line numbers

Comment: @deceze Yes, I've experienced that before, but it's usually 1 line off, not 8 or 9. Every bug I've had with this project has been several lines off for some reason.

Comment: Start with the assumption that the PHP debugger is alright. Then check if either your editor is numbering the lines incorrectly and/or whether there's whitespace in the files that is interpreted differently by your editor and PHP.

Comment: try putting something obviously wrong like `ecgo "dssd";` in your PHP file and see whether it gives you a wrong line number.

Comment: @JohnP I tried that on multiple lines. The further down the file I go, the more inaccurate it gets. Notepad++ and Eclipse agree that it is line 249 but PHP tells me it's 240. That is a good way for me to estimate how many lines it is off though, good tip. Thanks everyone for the help. This may just remain a mystery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's your line endings. Open up a program where you can change the line endings and change it to that of the server and the line number will be correct. I don't know about windows, but on mac you can change line endings using TextWrangler (or BBEdit) and on linux using gedit.

Comment: On Windows, Notepad++ works well for this. View > Show Symbol > Show End of Line. And to convert them, Edit > EOL Conversion > Whatever You Need

Comment: My line endings got doubled-up when I used FileZilla (I must have done something strange) and when converting them in Atom to LF I had to do it twice. This answer helped me figure it out though!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Logging function with a simple stacktrace.

Use it:

```
<?php
require_once("Log.class.php");
$myLog = new Log();

$log->write("Tag here", "Details here");
?>
```

Log.class.php:

```
<?php

    $debugFolder = "/";

    class ExpectedParamaterUndefinedException extends Exception {}

    class Log {

        private $logs = array();    

        function __contruct(){    
        }

        function write($type, $message){

            $trace=debug_backtrace();
            $caller=array_shift($trace);
            $fileParts = explode("/", $caller['file']);
            $filePieces =  explode(".", $fileParts[count($fileParts) -1]);
            $this->logs[  $filePieces [count($filePieces ) - 2] ] .= " [ ".date(DATE_RFC822)." ] [ $type ] [Line : ".$caller['line']."] ::: $message \n ";
        }

        function __destruct(){
            foreach($this->logs as $caller => $log){
                $fp=fopen($debugFolder . "debug/" . $caller.".log", "a");
                    fwrite($fp, $log);
            fclose($fp);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

You will end up with a .log file for each class that you log.

Happy hunting!